# How to make my python bot follow/unfollow ig users?

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram

guys so I'm a beginner in this field of programming and I'm having a small problem with my python bot. So I wanted to make a bot that follows/unfollows people on Instagram in specific intervals, but when I start the bot nothing happens, maybe I'm missing something.

here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/User/Desktop/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver")
webdriver.chrome.get("https://www.instagram.com/xmykolazx/")
sleep(4)
following = webdriver.chrome.find_element_by_partial_link_text("following")
following.click()
sleep(5)
for i in range(5):
    webdriver.chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Following"]') \
        .click()
    webdriver.chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Unfollow"]') \
        .click()
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: error on line 404

Comment: Have you checked that `find_element_by_partial_link_text` and `find_element_by_xpath` are returning the elements you are looking for?